# Change an XML without changing it in server

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I've got a llist of videos, with a click on a name it should display a video, the video-player i'm using read the video file name from a XML document in the same folder, I was thinking in, change the name of the file with javascript in the xml when a video name is clicked but I think this would change the original XML from the server and make it imposible for two people to view the page at the same time which actually sucks.
So is there any way to change only the XML on the user computer?
Or is there another way you can think to acomplish this job?

Comment: What kind of video player are you using? Browser plug-in (Flash, etc) or HTML5 player?

Comment: It is a Flash player for special videos www.lucid.it

Comment: Bergi's answer is correct in that you would need to ask the server to change the files name, but it seems like you need to save state (what video is selected), and changing the file name perhaps isn't  the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a (xml) file on the server easily. When you load it, the server will send you a stream of characters (call it string), which the browser will parse into a Document Object Model. This model is obvious locally, and when you modify it by using DOM manipulation methods like `setAttribute`, no one else will be affected.

To change a file on the server, you would need to explicitly request the server to do that.

Comment: OK, this was just my guess so I will code it and I will post here if this works. Thank you

Comment: It didn't work, I opened the xml with javascript using DOM, then changed the attribute which know which file to load , then I load the player, no change in it, it looks like still loading the old xml file from the server instead of using the one modified in the computer (I'm using wamp server to try it)

Comment: Of course, when that player loads the file itself it builds its own DOM - where no change happened. You will need to change the code/parameters of that player, please ask a specific question on that.